# How to find the last spwan thread or a process?

Tags: linux, node.js, process, ps

I am starting some custom process say a nodejs server on some custom ports by a script depending up the requests to that server. Now I want to kill the spawned servers depending on the last spawned process ID. How can I find which process(nodejs server) was started last?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting via a bash script, use the `$!` special variable to get the PID of the most-recently-backgrounded job. You'll have to store this when you spawn them if you want to later kill the last one. Note you must verify that the PID still corresponds to your node process just prior to killing it to make sure you don't kill some unrelated process that has re-used the same PID.